# PHP - Update HTML Select list to show current value

Tags: php, html

I'm working on a simple HTML form that will include a drop down list for the selected Salesperson. The list is coming from a database and is in an array that is stored in a variable $ids and looks like this:

```
Array ( [John Jones] => JJ [Sally Smith] => SS [Victor Howards] => VH [Barnie Kemp] => BK )
```

Here's how the select list is currently constructed:

```
<?php
                          $output = "";
                          $selected = false;

                          foreach ($ids as $id => $value) {

                              $output .= "<option value=\"$value\"";

                              if ($id == $record->getField('initials')) {
                                  $selected = true;
                                  $output .= " selected";
                                  $selectedID = $record->getField("id");
                              }
                              $output .= ">$id</option>";
                          }

                          if (!$selected) {
                              $chosen = $record->getField("initials");
                              $output = "<option value=\"$chosen\" selected>$chosen</option>$output";
                          }
                          echo $output;
                        ?>
```

I'm trying to update the select list to show the current value for this field as the selected option. I have the name/value stored in these variables:

```
$initials
$name
```

So if $initials = 'SS' I would like Sally Smith to be the selected value in the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use as simple as follow

```
<?php
      $output = "";

      foreach ($ids as $id => $value) {

          $selected = "";
          if ($id == $record->getField('initials')) {
              $selected = "selected";
          }

          $output .= "<option value='$value' $selected>$id</option>";           
      }
      echo $output;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not make your code complex.. do it like this one:

```
 $value=$record->getField('initials');
 foreach ($ids as $id => $valueData) {
    if($id==$value)
       echo "<option value='".$id."' selected='selected' >$id</option>";  
    else
           echo "<option value='".$id."'>$id</option>";  
}
```